# Not able to read variable in custom RStudio open-source application ,Azure ML

Tags: r, shell, sh, rstudio, azure-machine-learning-service

In Azure ML we have created compute instance by using setup shell script and we also installed custom RStudio open-source application using below MS docs
https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fmachine-learning%2Fhow-to-create-manage-compute-instance%3Ftabs%3Dpython%23setup-rstudio-open-source&data=05%7C01%7Cmaurivera%40microsoft.com%7Ce398077a3eaa41db3d9e08da908785e1%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637981209028277218%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=u7AsldLjg6jdSwqrQVG5CP9DPIModoop1fmmWciaHVs%3D&reserved=0

[AML compute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSGUv.png)

In setup shell script we define environment variable

```
#Create.Renviron file
r_env_file="/home/${aml_user}/.Renviron"
echo "Creating R environment variables"
sudo tee "${r_env_file}" > /dev/null <<EOF
AZURE_TENANT_ID=${AZURE_TENANT_ID}
AZURE_CLIENT_ID=${AZURE_CLIENT_ID}
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=${AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET}
DEFAULT_ADLS_ACCOUNT=${DEFAULT_ADLS_ACCOUNT}
DEFAULT_ADLS_CONTAINER=${DEFAULT_ADLS_CONTAINER}
EOF

sudo chown "${aml_user}" "${r_env_file}"
sudo chmod 600 "${r_env_file}"
```

In terminal we are able to read above variable
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frZ8d.png)

However, we are not able to read above variable in custom RStudio open-source application.

Comment: The machine learning studio SDK for R was deprecated and there is no support for R from 2021 end. Kindly check with R training and deployment experience using Azure Machine Learning CLI 2.0. Check with the below link for reference: https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/tree/main/cli/jobs/single-step/r

Answer (score 0):

The R portal is different from R Studio. Some of the required libraries are not installed and there is a challenge to get installed them in the R IDLE in ML Notebook. To get the RStudio to get worked in ML Studio, follow the below procedure.

The compute instances setup has changed. Get the license of RStudio by following the procedure mentioned below. As it is a professional version, we need to get the license first and use it.

[image]

By default, there will be no RStudio.

[image]

Create an instance

[image]

Add application as shown in the option.

Go to RStudio and get the license for workbench.

[image]

[image]

Get license from official RStudio account.

[image]

[image]

Give the details required and target the port 8787 and published port will be 8787. Open RStudio which was downloaded with license.

1. Select Custom Application under Applications
2. Fill in the details of the applications, like Application Name
3. Set the target port as 8787
4. Set the publish port as 8787
5. Set the Docker image as the target.
6. Under /home/azureuser/cloudfiles set the Host path and Container path
7. Click on Create

[image]

Finally you can see the RStudio as the workbench.